# Change colour of a shape in Java for Android after user input

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, shapes

I have a simple shape that is stored in rect.xml, and included in an other xml as a 'background' attribute of a 'View'. The two codes are:

\res\layout\rect.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/shape"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#aaaaff" />
<padding
android:left="5dp"
android:top="5dp"
android:right="5dp"
android:bottom="5dp"    >
</padding>
<solid android:color="#E6121A" />
<gradient
android:startColor="#000000"
android:endColor="#aaaaff"
android:angle="90"  >
</gradient>

<corners
android:radius="10dp"
android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp" >
</corners>

</shape>
```

my other view, that is displayed as content of an activity includes this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="@layout/rect" />
```

I would like to set the android:endColor attribute to another colour, the startColor is always the same. 
Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but based on the information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) 
you should be able to set the colors with this:

```java
GradientDrawable gradient = (GradientDrawable)yourView.getBackground();

int startColor = Color.BLACK;
int endColor = Color.RGB(0, 2, 255);
gradient.setColors(new int[]{ startColor, endColor });
```

Please note that GradientDrawable.setColors() was added in API level 16/Android 4.1 (thanks [unrulygnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572596/unrulygnu)!), and to support earlier versions you need to create and set a new `GradientDrawable` every time you want to change colors, like this:

```java
GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{startColor, endColor});
gradient.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
yourView.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
```

Comment: This does work (tested); however, the `GradientDrawable.setColors()` method was added to the platform in JellyBean (API 16).  If support for ICS (or previous) is required, then there are more hoops to jump through... probably something along the lines of storing the colors as resources, then building the backgrounds at runtime.

Comment: Thanks @unrulygnu, I wasn't aware of that. Included in original answer.